# Docker build and push git code inside Azure devops

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I have a docker file which copies some code from git. When I put this docker file as part of Azure devops pipeline I am unable to get the code inside container. is git clone the only option or is there any way out of this?

Answer (score 0):

The container is not having internet access to connect to the git repository. You can prebuild your image from local system and use the image from docker images registry.